# How can I center my image + text and keep responsive?

Tags: html, css

here's the result I'd like to obtain once I'm reducing the window : [image]

the problem in this result is that they aren't centered, once I center them that's what I get, I guess I'm doing something wrong : [the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOz5y.jpg). This code is the one that cause the issue when they're centered.

Here's my code :

```css
section {
    margin-top: 25px;
    padding: 24px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h2 {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;  
    align-content: flex-start;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 15x;

  }

  .flex-container > div{
    position: relative;
    left: 21%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 8px;
  }

.articleactu img {
    float: left;
  border-radius: 15px;
  max-width: 210px;
}

p {
   word-wrap: break-word;
   max-width: 900px;
   padding-left: 200px;
}

#titre {
    line-height: px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#date {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #662189;
}

hr.solid {
  position: relative;
  left: 21%;
  width: 50%;
  opacity: 12%;
} 

div p ,#titre ,#date {
    margin-left: 35px;
}
```

```html
<!-- ACTUALITÉ - ARTICLES -->

  <section>
      <h2> L'ACTUALITÉ </h2>
    <article class="articleactu">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div>
      <img src="images/gtaarticle.jpeg" alt="Article GTA " class="center">
        <p id="titre">GTA : THE TRILOGY DEFINITIVE EDITION, les fans sont déçus !</p>
        <p> Les joueurs attendaient une refonte complète de la trilogie afin de rappeler de lointains souvenirs mais malheureusement les fans sont déçus...</p>
        <p id="date"> Publié le 27 novembre 2021 </p>
    </div>

<hr class="solid">

    <div>
      <img src="images/bf2042-2.jpg" alt="Article GTA " class="center">
        <p id="titre">BATTLEFIELD 2042 : De très mauvaise notes pour le nouvel opus.</p>
        <p> Le lancement du jeu est malheureusement un raté... Un jeu rempli de bugs, on repense évidemment à Cyberpunk 2077...</p>
        <p id="date"> Publié le 26 novembre 2021 </p>
    </div>

<hr class="solid">

    </article>
  </section>
```

I hope that anyone can help me with this. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is

```
.flex-container > div{
    left: 21%;
}
```

Then, that div has full width(100%) but the left position has 21%. So the content will look on the left side.

Try like this.

```
section {
    margin-top: 25px;
    padding: 24px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h2 {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;  
    align-content: flex-start;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10%;

  }
.flex-container > div {
  display: flex;
}
.flex-container > div > div {
  float: left;
}

.description {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.articleactu img {
    border-radius: 15px;
    max-width: 210px;
}

p {
   word-wrap: break-word;
}

#titre {
    line-height: px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#date {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #662189;
}

hr.solid {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  opacity: 12%;
}
```

your HTML

```
<section>
    <h2> L'ACTUALITÉ </h2>
    <article class="articleactu">
      <div class="flex-container">
        <div style="display: flex">
          <div>
            <img src="images/gtaarticle.jpeg" alt="Article GTA " class="center">
          </div>
          <div class="description">
            <p id="titre">GTA : THE TRILOGY DEFINITIVE EDITION, les fans sont déçus !</p>
            <p> Les joueurs attendaient une refonte complète de la trilogie afin de rappeler de lointains souvenirs mais malheureusement les fans sont déçus...</p>
            <p id="date"> Publié le 27 novembre 2021 </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <hr class="solid">

        <div>
          <div>
            <img src="images/bf2042-2.jpg" alt="Article GTA " class="center">
          </div>
          <div  class="description">
            <p id="titre">BATTLEFIELD 2042 : De très mauvaise notes pour le nouvel opus.</p>
            <p> Le lancement du jeu est malheureusement un raté... Un jeu rempli de bugs, on repense évidemment à Cyberpunk 2077...</p>
            <p id="date"> Publié le 26 novembre 2021 </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <hr class="solid">
      </div>
    </article>
  </section>
```

Comment: Nice, that works. But I need it to be centered how could I do now? I was using "left" but now it isn't in it anymore ?

Comment: `.flex-container {
    padding: 10%;
}`    your content is arranged as a center by this code already. If you want to further narrow the width of the content, you can adjust the `padding` value.(ex: 20%)

Comment: From what I'm seeing on my page it isn't centered. I pasted your code to try but it's weird that it isn't centered to my others content.

Comment: I did, adjusted to 21, it was centered but really low in my page. + responsive was really weird, like the text would be letter by letter vertical

Comment: Ah. I see. Please remove the this  `line.hr.solid { left: 21%;} `

Comment: That doesn't change anything :/